# fully track of a mail in evolution. Thread of a mail

Tags: evolution, mail

How can I see the thread of in a evolution conversation so that it includes my answers to the conversation?
Evolution's way of showing threads is only from incoming emails.
That is, how can I fully track an email, including my shares, in evolution?

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this is to save your replies in the same folder as the received mails. There is an option to make this the default behavior for an account. It is found under: Edit->Accounts, select your email account and hit edit.  And check the option "Save replies in the folder of the messages being replied to".
[image: Screenshot of Account Editor Window]

Comment: On my evolution I had to go to Edit->Preferences->Mail Accounts, then select and edit to get to the same menu

Answer (score 1):

- Click the message you want to read in thread
- Choose Show as **Message Thread**

  [image: Message Thread picture]
- Make sure you have **View -> Group By Threads** checked

Comment: Yes, but this form only shows the emails that I have received. Not the ones that I have sent

Comment: In my case it contains both Received and Sent mails. Do you have **View -> Group by threads** checked?

Comment: Maybe it's because I move my outgoing messages to another folder, although this is inside the sent folder

Comment: Hi @RodrigoFilippi did you find a solution for this? I use office365 in evolution. My inbox is called `Inbox` and it has threaded view - but is missing my sent mail. And my send folder is called `Sent Items`, and it also has threaded view - but there are no emails from the inbox. Did you find a solution to sync the threads of two folders?